# How to change root directory of project file browser in Source Insight 3.5

Tags: source-insight

I am trying to change the root directory of project file browser
because the project file is not in c:. I have already checked out the documents in source insight official site but seems like no way to change it or I miss it. Does anyone know how to config it? Thanks a lot!

[image: root directory of project file browser]

Answer (score 1):

In front of the Directory, Just type the root directory (eg:D:)
as follow image then you can make it.

[image]